# 'variable '__p_1' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FileModel]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Using Net 6 and Entity Framework Core I have the query:

```
var models = context.Posts
  .Select(x => new Model {
    Id = x.Id,
    Files = 
      !fieldsToLoad.Contains("files") ? new List<FileModel>() :
        x.PostFiles.Select(y => new FileModel {
          Id = y.File.Id,
        })
    }).ToListAsync();
```

This query was running on Net Core 5 but with Net 6 I get the exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FileModel>'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead.
```

I then used local variables:

```
var loadFiles = fieldsToLoad.Contains("files");

files = new List<FileModel>(); // Strangely I had to also add this

var models = context.Posts
  .Select(x => new Model {
    Id = x.Id,
    Files = 
      loadFiles ? 
      x.PostFiles.Select(y => new FileModel {
        Id = y.File.Id,
      }) :
      files
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Now I get the error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'variable '__p_1' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FileModel]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'
```

This only happens if `loadFiles` is `false` so the post `Files` would be `files`, e.g.,  and empty list of `FileModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Entity Framework tries to translate the entire LINQ query into SQL. There is no SQL equivalent for either `fieldsToLoad` of `files`, which the exception messages try to tell quite cryptically.

You need a different approach to load files conditionally. If you'd query the full entities you could add `Include` conditionally, but you project to a model, so `Include` doesn't apply.

I would use AutoMapper and create a mapping profile that ignores the `PostFiles` property conditionally.

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
...

class PostMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public PostMappingProfile(bool ignoreFiles)
    {
        CreateMap<PostFile, FileModel>();
        var mapping = CreateMap<Post, Model>();
        if (ignoreFiles)
        {
            mapping.ForMember(dest => dest.PostFiles, m => m.Ignore());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var conf = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
    cfg.AddProfile(new PostMappingProfile(true)));

var models = await context.Posts.ProjectTo<Model>(conf).ToListAsync();
```

Assuming that properties in `Model` and `FileModel` have the same names as in the entity classes. If not, you have to add mapping instructions to the mapping profile.